# .net framework 4.5 not getting installed with the Setup.exe

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am trying to install .net framework 4.5 on windows 7 32bit machine remotely. When I run the dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe file, the log says, contents failed to extract. Drives have enough space also.

So I try to extract the exe content and try to install it using the setup.exe file. So the .net installation blocker I receive is -- [image]

Can somebody please help, what file should I use for installation of framework 4.5 after extraction.

Comment: that is x86_x64.exe file.. Common for both

Comment: Yep tried after restarting the machine.

Comment: Check the log files, in \Windows\TEMP and the like

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Setup.exe /x86
```

or

```
Setup.exe /x64
```

depending on whether your operating system is 32-bit or 64-bit respectively.